# symfony2: How to setting the value of field, outside the form

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables:

[image]

For each new record in the table **Liquidaciones** I need set the field value **comisiones_id** (for example: 2), outside the form

This is a special case because **comisiones_id** field is related to the table **Comisiones**

When I try to set the value, in **LiquidacionesController.php** with:

```
 $liquidacione = new Liquidaciones();
    $form = $this->createForm('BackendBundle\Form\LiquidacionesType', $liquidacione);
    $form->get('comisiones')->setData('2');


    $form->handleRequest($request);
```

I get the following error message:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to BackendBundle\Entity\Liquidaciones::setComisiones() must be an instance of BackendBundle\Entity\Comisiones, string given, called in C:\proyectos\cursospierobis\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php on line 556 and defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here my files:

**LiquidacionesController.php**

```
   public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $liquidacione = new Liquidaciones();
    $form = $this->createForm('BackendBundle\Form\LiquidacionesType', $liquidacione);
        $form->get('comisiones')->setData('2');
    $form->handleRequest($request);



    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($liquidacione);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('liquida_show', array('id' => $liquidacione->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('liquidaciones/new.html.twig', array(
        'liquidacione' => $liquidacione,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**LiquidacionesType.php**

```
class LiquidacionesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nroLiqui')
            ->add('fechaPago', null, array('widget' => 'single_text'))
            ->add('monto')
            ->add('observaciones')
            ->add('comisiones', 'hidden')
                ;

    }

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'BackendBundle\Entity\Liquidaciones'
    ));
}
}
```

And Entity **Liquidaciones.php**:

```
namespace BackendBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Liquidaciones
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="liquidaciones", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_Liquidaciones_Comisiones1_idx", columns={"comisiones_id"})})
 *  @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BackendBundle\Entity\LiquidacionesRepository")
 */

********************

  public function setComisiones(\BackendBundle\Entity\Comisiones $comisiones)
{
    $this->comisiones = $comisiones;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get comisiones
 *
 * @return \BackendBundle\Entity\Comisiones 
 */
public function getComisiones()
{
    return $this->comisiones;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Using the solution proposed by **Iaroslav Gashuk**, the code would look like:

**LiquidacionesController.php**

```
public function newAction(Request $request )
{
    $liquidacione = new Liquidaciones();


    $form = $this->createForm('BackendBundle\Form\LiquidacionesType', $liquidacione);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {   

        $comisiones = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('BackendBundle:Comisiones')->findOneById(4);
        $liquidacione->setComisiones($comisiones);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($liquidacione);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('liquidaciones_show', array('id' => $liquidacione->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('liquidaciones/new.html.twig', array(
        'liquidacione' => $liquidacione,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an instance of your `Comisiones` entity instead of its id

Comment: To set an associated entity, fetch it by its id: `$comisiones = $em->getRepository('BackednBundle:Comisiones')->find($id);` and pass it to the appropriate method: `$liquidacione->setComisiones($comisiones);`

Comment: @laroslav Gashuk Apologies for delay my response. You are right.

Comment: In my case, I use Symfony 2.8.3, the code works like this: `$comisiones = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('BackendBundle:Comisiones')->findOneById(2);
            $liquidacione->setComisiones($comisiones);`